# Why does typescript subtype work with class generics but not with method generics?

Tags: typescript, oop, design-patterns, types

I have this code here, with one type extending another one and one interface typed to use the former and a second one typed to use the latter:

```js
interface BaseType {
    a: number;
}

interface DerivedType extends BaseType{
    b: number;
}

interface BaseInterface1<T extends BaseType> {
    m1(p: T): T
}

interface DerivedInterface1 extends BaseInterface1<DerivedType> {
    m1(p: DerivedType): DerivedType
}
```

All good, it builds and it does what I want.

But now let's say that I want to move my generics to the `m1` method rather than to the whole interface, how could I do it?

Something I've tried is:

```js
interface BaseInterface2 {
    m1<T extends BaseType>(p: T): T
}

interface DerivedInterface2 extends BaseInterface2 {
    m1<T extends DerivedType>(p: T): T
}
```

I thought this would have meant that I was creating a new interface typed with a stricter type but it doesn't really work. I can see how this might indeed break the type covariance and controvariance.
I get an error: `Property 'b' is missing in type 'BaseType' but required in type 'DerivedType'.`

Something else I tried is

```js
interface BaseInterface3 {
    m1<T extends BaseType>(p: T): T
}

interface DerivedInterface3 extends BaseInterface3 {
    m1(p: DerivedType): DerivedType
}
```

Again I thought reyfing the generics might help but it doesn't. The error here is:
`Type 'T' is not assignable to type 'DerivedType'. Type 'BaseType' is not assignable to type 'DerivedType'.`. Again potentially a problem with type covariance and controvariance.

What am I doing wrong? How can I fix this?

An additional explenation on why I'm doing this.

In my case the derived interface would be a facade over a fairly complex system and there would be a lot of method rather than only `m1`. This means that I would prefer to have a separate generic on every method rather than a long list of unrelated generics on the class.

Comment: You can't do this because the contract is that BaseInterface2 must be assignable to DerivedInterface2. If you change the generic constraint to something "tighter", then you break that contract since function parameters and type parameters are contravariant. I don't know what kind of fixes you are looking for. Workarounds? Alternatives?

Comment: I agree with @katniss. Generic types (where the type param is on the *type*, like `interface I<T>{⋯}`) allow the *supplier* to specify the type argument, while generic functions  (where the type parameter is on the *call signature*, like `f<T>(⋯): ⋯`) allow the *consumer* to specify the type argument.  You can't just change the scope of a generic type parameter and expect things to stay the same.   As for how you "fix" it, it really depends on the use case, but the only description of your use case seems to be "I want to move my generics". To what end?

Comment: I've added an explanation on why I'm trying to move the generics from the class from the methods. @jcalz I understand what you mean exepct when you said that the scope of the generic type parameter changes. To me it looks like it's always specific to that one method.

Comment: ① The difference between `class A { m<T>(t: T): void }` and `class A<T> { m(t: T): void }` is the scope of `T`; in the former, every instance and subclass of class `A` has to have an `m` method that works for every `T` the caller chooses to use. In the latter, you will only have instances of classes or subclasses like `A<T>` for some specific `T` chosen by the creator of the instance or the subclass, and then the caller of the `m` method has no choice.  It's the difference between `x => () => x` and `() => x => x`.

Comment: ② "I would prefer to have a separate generic on every method rather than a long list of unrelated generics on the class."  But you can't have that and keep the behavior you like.  Conceptually the generics belong on the class, and your preferences don't change that.  If I drop my car keys on a dark street, I might prefer to look for them on another more well-lit street, but that doesn't really accomplish my goal.  So, what should we do here?  Write up an answer saying this is impossible?